# edgePreload.js conflicting with jQuery.ScrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I am using Edge animate for a header on my webpage. I am trying to incorporate the slide effect from page to page utilizing the jQuery.ScrollTo plugin courtesy of Ariel Flesler. The problem is that when I include the

```
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="spolightest_edgePreload.js"></script>
```

the slide effect stops working. I have narrowed it down to this file so I know that this is causing the problem. Any one ever deal with this problem? Does anyone know a better way to accomplish the slide effect in a webpage. It is quite a large amount of javascript to include here, so here is my site that I am trying to make this work on. You can view the script there.

www.premierentertainmentevents.com

I've tried to call the javascript files in different order, including the hosted jquery library from google, include the jqueryscroll.js in the edge preload file..

I'm at a loss. Something is conflicting with something else and I have no idea what.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see from your page is that the scripts include order isn't correct right now.

You are including jquery after the adobe edge's includes, so that in the console I can see the errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /spolightest_edge.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined spolightest_edgeActions.js:8
```

I know you tried different things, but please include jquery above anything else so maybe I can see if other errors occur.